# How to fix that Sublime Text runs a wrong file from its command terminal?

Tags: python, terminal, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, package-control

I have 2 `.py` files that called `tag_to_top.py` and `color_changer.py`. Each file is contained in their individual package folders so they are completely separated. They have different file directories.

Now here's the problem. When I run the file called `color_changer.py` using `view.run_command("color_changer")` inside of the Sublime Text terminal, the output does not match what it should be from the `color_changer.py`. It seems like the terminal of ST runs different code.

Here are the details of the code

```
# tag_to_top.py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class TagToTopCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, tag=None):
        tag_lines = self.view.find_all(r"^\s*((#\w+)\s*){1,}")
        print()
        print("hello world 2")

# color_changer.py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

file_path = './log.txt'

with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        if line.startswith(r'\s'):
            num_empty_spaces = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
            print(f"Line {line_number}: {num_empty_spaces} empty spaces")
```

The output from the code is fixed to a result of `tag_to_top.py`, `(empty line) \n hello world 2`. No matter which files run inside of the terminal, it always throws the same output.

When I run `tag_to_top.py`, throws the result of `tag_to_top.py`,

When I run `color_changer.py`, it also throws the result of `tag_to_top.py`.

Are there any ways to fix this without re-installing ST?

Comment: Could that be a bug in ST? Try closing the app and restarting the system

Comment: Also if you have another IDE like VSCode or IDLE, try it and see if you get the same thing

Comment: @journpy I've just restarted my Mac and it doesn't work.

Comment: can you try another IDE?

Comment: @journpy I migrated my all `.py` files from their directories to `Packages/Users` folder and then put it back into them but still problem isn't gone. This method was  an answer and a solution to someone where I found a similar question that I have right now from this website

Comment: @journpy I tried logging it on VSC but it says there's no module name 'sublime'. And I don't know where i can download a `sublime module`.

Comment: oh i see, it seems to be a plugin for ST.